# Navigation using SCORM 2004: doSetValue("adl.nav.request","continue") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, moodle, scorm

I'm using the standard SCORM 2004 4th format. 
I'm using the ADL starter_template, and I tried to use the JS commands `doSetValue("adl.nav.request","continue"); doTerminate();` called by a simple button, to pass to the SCO-3 from the SCO-2.
I used the starter_template manifest.
In run-time with moodle 2.6 I found this JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
scorm_next
scorm_launch_next_sco
```

I don't know if I must modify the manifest file, in the http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/SCORM_Users_Guide_for_Programmers.pdf guide is written that it should work with original manifest.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

That actually sounds like a JavaScript 'bug' error.  You didn't mention which LMS or portal you were using so was this ADL wrappers or tests?

Thanks,
Mark